# BVH importing what's going wrong?

Tags: animation, bones

After look to a couple of tutorials about import .bvh files on Blender I came across with a weird thing on my imports.

I've captured some movements with a motion capture system, It exports a .bvh file as usual but whenever I import them on Blender, it creates a enormous bone and the 19 points of motion capture along it.

Here's a screenshot. In it, you can see the T-position (the points, and the big bone)

BVH added: http://www.pasteall.org/66043/c (as c for whatever)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bvh (pasteall.org) file and also in a screen shot with the rig selected an image of outliner expanded to show the bone structure ?

Comment: I've tried with another model and the skeleton seems to be exported fine, however It doesn't move. I'm exporting from Autodesk MotionBuilder 2010. Blender can see the keyframes but it's not playing at all. It keeps static.

Comment: bvh added to the OP

Comment: I get skeleton ok, weird rest post, no animation from link bvh.  A quick peruse of the data (line 493 and on) and it doesn't appear to change, each bone's fcurve is a flat line, hence no animation showing in blender.  In other words it's imported ok into blender, there must be some hassle with the way you are exporting from motion builder.